# How to configure GCP project for a data science challenge?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm a student and I want to organize data science challenge in my school, I want to use `Google Cloud Platform` as `infrastructure`. There is 43 teams that participate in the challange, and the idea is to create envirement in `GCP` and give access for the 43 teams to work for 12 hours to solve a data science problimatic, technique envirement is `Rstudio` and `ancaconda`. They will work with 200 Mg of data and only we will use CPU, I thinks that we require 4 vms to work with so we must install all the envirement in the 4 vms and gives access to all the 43 teams.

any advice and help. is there other solution?

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is possible making use of Google's Identity and Access Management. Roles can be assigned to individual members, and their access to services can be restricted.

By using what are called IAM attributes it is also possible to restrict access on a time basis. There are resource and request attributes.

The resource attributes are used to restrict access to resources, the request attributes restrict at what time requests can be sent. See the following for [Resource Attributes](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-overview#resource_attributes), and here for [Request Attributes](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-overview#request_attributes)

As for RStudio you should review the following documentation that details how to use Rstudio with Google Cloud ML [R Interface to Google CloudML](https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/tools/cloudml/getting_started/), and also here [Getting Started with RStudio Connect for GCP](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360033988434-Getting-Started-with-RStudio-Connect-for-GCP)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I want to send just URLs of JupyterLab and Rstudio(http://(instance-1 or 127.0.0.1):8888/) to the competitors and they login into jupyterlab and Rstudio(they can choose one of them) is that possible? or they must login to GCP consol?